# Uploading files to server from PHP

Tags: php, webserver

I am using the following script to upload files from a web site to the server

```
<?php if ((isset($_POST["enviado"])) && ($_POST["enviado"]=="form1")){
$length = 10;

$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

$prefijo =  $randomString;


    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"platos/".$prefijo.$nombre_archivo);



    ?>
```

The selected file is uploaded to the folder `platos`.

On another web site, I am using the same script, the only change is the name of the folder, but the selected file is not uploaded.

This is the script used on the second site:

```
<?php if ((isset($_POST["enviado"])) && ($_POST["enviado"]=="form1")){
$length = 10;

$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

$prefijo =  $randomString;


    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"docs/".$prefijo.$nombre_archivo);



    ?>
```

I am not able to detect the error...

EDITED, COMPLETE CODE HERE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Subir Factura PFD</title>

</head>



<body>



<?php if ((isset($_POST["enviado"])) && ($_POST["enviado"]=="form1")){
$length = 10;

$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

$prefijo =  $randomString;


    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"docs/".$prefijo.$nombre_archivo);



    ?>

    <script>

    opener.document.form1.pdf_factura.value="<?php echo $prefijo.$nombre_archivo;?>";

    self.close();

    </script>





    <?php 

}

else {?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="subirPDF.php" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <p>

    <input name="userfile" type="file" />

  </p>

  <p>

    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Subir imagen" />

    <input type="hidden" name="enviado" value="form1" />

  </p>

</form>

<?php }?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How big is the file you are uploading? There are a few file size limit mechanisms.

Comment: @Jake, The file is only 28KB

Comment: @Jake, on the first site I am uploading image files. On the second site I am trying to upload PDF and text files...

Comment: Upload the same thing and see if it works? Check for folder permissions?

Comment: @Jake, it doesn't work. I am uploading the same image file on both sites and the PDF file on both sites. On the first server, both files, image and PDF are uploaded, on the second server none of the files are uploaded.

Comment: Check and set the upload folder permission to 777.

Comment: @amit, thanks,but already done and not solved.

Comment: Can you please post your upload form's HTML code here, too? Thanks.

Comment: @chaensel, yes, of course....I will update my question right now. Thanks

Comment: I have tried your complete script on my windows machine. It works perfetly fine in my surrounding AFTER I have changed the action of the form... It tries to submit the data to "subirPDF.php". I removed the action to make the form call the same page/itself. It worked. Sorry for not being more helpful

Comment: @chaensel, subirPDF.php is the name of the file. On the first site it is working as it is. How should I change the form action to make the form call as you did?

Comment: @mvasco I have simply removed the action :) So I just deleted `action="subirPDF.php"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are running this on a windows machine: I have run into kind of the same problem. `move_uploaded_file()` didn't work out for me because of (weird) folder permissions. 
I used the PHP function `copy()` instead of `move_uploaded_file()`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you need to check "upload_max_filesize" and "post_max_size" paramter in your php.ini file.

These should be greater than the size of file you are trying to uploading.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2M
; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 2M
```

After modifying php.ini file, you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

if above parameters are ok then check the directory permission and owner.

Answer (score 1):

check **permissions on the directory** in which you are uploading the file:

try doing:

`chmod -R 777 docs`

Note: The docs directory must be writable so that file can be added in this directory.